# Android GraphView Gradle "Failed to run" Error?

Tags: android, graph, build, gradle

i need to do more graph in my app and i thought to import that library ( http://www.android-graphview.org/ ).

I just follow the rules and i add to the gradle the compile row.

That is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.btc.btcmobile"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.0.0'
}
```

after that, i copy-paste the example on the site, but when i compile now i can see that error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\valerio\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\valerio\Desktop\BtcMobile\btcmobile\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\valerio\Desktop\BtcMobile\btcmobile\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/jjoe64/graphview/BuildConfig;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

How i can resolve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the ***GraphView4.1.jar*** inside the libs folder. I also had ***compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.0.1'*** in the build.gradle. As soon as I removed the jar file from libs folder, the *com.android.dex.DexException* error was resolved.